# What are the changes in metric properties for Hikari in Spring Boot 3.0?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

everyone! Why did the `Hikari` metrics stop working in my application after upgrading to `Spring Boot 3.0`? I'm currently using the following dependencies:

```
implementation('io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.8.4')
implementation('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-statsd:1.8.4')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
```

And these configurations:

```
management.statsd.metrics.export.host=datadog
management.metrics.enable.hikaricp=true
```

Do I need to make any changes to get the Hikari metrics working again?

I attempted to upgrade the dependencies and modify the metrics configuration due to the changes in StatsD on Spring Boot 3.0.

Comment: Did you find out the solution? We are seeing same issue